# Spritebuilder sprite position changes

Tags: position, sprite, spritebuilder

I have my game in spritebuilder, and I am trying to move a ball up every 0.005 seconds. I have an `NSTimer` doing that, but sometimes `ball.position.y + 2` is different.

For instance, one time I play the game, the ball moves to the top of the screen at the speed I want it to. Then, without even closing the game, just opening the scene again, the ball moves at half of the speed, as if `+ 2` isn't as much at that time, or the `NSTimer` decides to run at half speed.

NOTE: This only happens on an actual device. I can't get it to happen in a simulator.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Thanks.

EDIT: My code (abridged):

```
timer2 = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.005, target: self, selector: "updateTick", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

My update function:

```
func updateTick() {
    ...
    incrementBalls()
    ...
}
```

My `incrementBalls()` function:

```
for index in 0...balls.count - 1 {
    balls[index].position = ccpAdd(_physicsBody.position, CGPoint(x: balls[index].position.x, y: balls[index].position.y + 2))
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by instead using the update method and doing some math to move the balls instead of the unreliable NSTimer.